# Hibernate creates multiple foreign keys in database tables for bidirectional associations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I want to create the following tables with the necessary associations accordingly:
[image]

However, it seems that I have miyed up something because when Hibernate creates the tables multiple foreign keys are created as shown below:

> INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@5e5595f3]
>   for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the
>   Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection
>   will be set into auto-commit mode.
>
> Hibernate: create table APP.ITEMS (ITEM_ID integer generated by
>   default as identity, NAME varchar(100), NET_PRICE integer, VAT_RATE
>   integer, CATEGORY_ID integer not null, primary key (ITEM_ID))
>
> Hibernate: create table APP.LIMIT (LIMIT_ID integer not null,
>   LIMIT_VALUE integer, primary key (LIMIT_ID))
>
> Hibernate: create table APP.PARTNER (PARTNER_ID integer generated by
>   default as identity, PARTNER_NAME varchar(100), primary key
>   (PARTNER_ID))
>
> Hibernate: create table APP.TRANSACTIONS (TRANSACTIONS_ID integer
>   generated by default as identity, FLOW integer not null, NET_PRICE
>   integer, ITEM_ID integer not null, advicenote integer, ADVICENOTE_ID
>   integer not null, primary key (TRANSACTIONS_ID))
>
> Hibernate: alter table APP.TRANSACTIONS add constraint
>   UK_r7btjtpy72nugbhuia8y0xnk6 unique (ITEM_ID)
>
> Hibernate: alter table APP.ADVICENOTE add constraint
>   FK4n4r6ej5i983gk8fqj20jl899 **foreign key (partner)** references
>   APP.PARTNER
>
> Hibernate: alter table APP.ADVICENOTE add constraint
>   FKr96drd4j6pds8vocvsstcd2a2 **foreign key (PARTNER_ID)** references
>   APP.PARTNER
>
> Hibernate: alter table APP.ITEMS add constraint
>   FKbbkng91eiiqu522okqq0nq7pm foreign key (CATEGORY_ID) references
>   APP.CATEGORIES
>
> Hibernate: alter table APP.TRANSACTIONS add constraint
>   FK13kk35nfl3iff7f2cs8er8w0s **foreign key (advicenote)** references
>   APP.ADVICENOTE
>
> Hibernate: alter table APP.TRANSACTIONS add constraint
>   FK8ilbnqyk8lemxj0yvbqm3p7tt foreign key (ITEM_ID) references APP.ITEMS
>
> Hibernate: alter table APP.TRANSACTIONS add constraint
>   FKqrbn7tojjjkjyusy98a300btp **foreign key (ADVICENOTE_ID)** references
>   APP.ADVICENOTE
>
> Hibernate: select categories0_.NAME as col_0_0_ from APP.CATEGORIES
>   categories0_
>
> Hibernate: select items0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID1_2_, items0_.NAME as
>   NAME2_2_, items0_.NET_PRICE as NET_PRIC3_2_, items0_.VAT_RATE as
>   VAT_RATE4_2_, items0_.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY5_2_ from APP.ITEMS
>   items0_
>
> Hibernate: select items0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID1_2_, items0_.NAME as
>   NAME2_2_, items0_.NET_PRICE as NET_PRIC3_2_, items0_.VAT_RATE as
>   VAT_RATE4_2_, items0_.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY5_2_ from APP.ITEMS
>   items0_
>
> Hibernate: select categories0_.NAME as col_0_0_ from APP.CATEGORIES
>   categories0_
>
> Hibernate: select items0_.ITEM_ID as ITEM_ID1_2_, items0_.NAME as
>   NAME2_2_, items0_.NET_PRICE as NET_PRIC3_2_, items0_.VAT_RATE as
>   VAT_RATE4_2_, items0_.CATEGORY_ID as CATEGORY5_2_ from APP.ITEMS
>   items0_

Is this normal behaviour or am I missing something?

Here are my XML mappings:

Advicenote.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Feb 9, 2019, 3:57:52 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Advicenote" table="ADVICENOTE" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="advicenoteId" type="int" column="ADVICENOTE_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="advicedate" type="date" column="ADVICE_DATE" length="10" />
        <property name="inOrOut" type="java.lang.Short" column="IN_OR_OUT" />
        <many-to-one 
            name="partner" class="classes.Partner"/>  
        <set name="transactions" table="TRANSACTIONS" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="true" fetch="select">       
            <key column="ADVICENOTE_ID" not-null="true"/>
            <one-to-many class="classes.Transactions"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Categories.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Categories" table="CATEGORIES" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="categoryId" type="int">
            <column name="CATEGORY_ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="100" />
        </property>
     <set name="items" table="ITEMS" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="false" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="CATEGORY_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="classes.Items" />
    </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Items.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Items" table="ITEMS" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="itemId" type="int" column="ITEM_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string" column="NAME" length="100"/>
        <property name="netPrice" type="java.lang.Integer" column="NET_PRICE"/>
        <property name="vatRate" type="java.lang.Integer" column="VAT_RATE"/>
        <many-to-one name="category" class="classes.Categories" fetch="select" column="CATEGORY_ID" not-null="true" lazy="false"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Limit.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Limit" table="LIMIT" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="limitId" type="java.lang.Integer" column="LIMIT_ID">
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>
        <property name="value" type="int" column="LIMIT_VALUE" length="1000"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Partner.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Partner" table="PARTNER" schema="APP">
        <id name="partnerId" type="int">
            <column name="PARTNER_ID"/>
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="partnerName" type="string" column="PARTNER_NAME" length="100"/>
        <set name="advicenotes" table="ADVICENOTE" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key column="PARTNER_ID" not-null="true"/>
            <one-to-many class="classes.Advicenote" />
        </set>
            </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Transactions.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Transactions" table="TRANSACTIONS" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="transactionsId" type="int" column="TRANSACTIONS_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="flow" type="int" column="FLOW" not-null="true" />
        <property name="netPrice" type="java.lang.Integer" column="NET_PRICE" />

        <many-to-one name="advicenote" class="classes.Advicenote"/>
        <many-to-one name="item" class="classes.Items" fetch="select" cascade="save-update" column="ITEM_ID" unique="true" not-null="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

An AdviceNote mapping JoinColumn is missing

```
<many-to-one name="partner" class="classes.Partner">
   <join-column name="PARTNER_ID"/>
</many-to-one>
```